# How to fix TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, flask

I have been following a 3 year old tutorial for making a web app and I encountered this error:

```py
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.  shows that error occurs on line: form = AddLocation(request.form)
```

Nowhere in my code do I have `__init__()`

**Route.py**

```py
@app.route('/addlocation', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_location():
    
    form = AddLocation(request.form)
    places = Place.query.all()
    categories = Category.query.all()
    
    
    
    if request.method =="POST":
    
        name = form.name.data
        desc = form.desc.data
        rating = form.rating.data
        cord = form.cord.data
        place = request.form.get('place')
        category = request.form.get('category')
    #/ep11
        image_1 = photos.save(request.files.get('image_1'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        image_2 = photos.save(request.files.get('image_2'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        image_3 = photos.save(request.files.get('image_3'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        image_4 = photos.save(request.files.get('image_4'), name=secrets.token_hex(10) + ".")
        #ovde definisemo koji podatak ide u koju kolonu
        addloc = AddLocation(name=name, desc=desc, rating=rating, cord=cord, place_id=place, category_id=category, image_1=image_1, image_2=image_2, image_3=image_3, image_4=image_4)
        db.session.add(addloc)
        flash(f'Lokacija {name} je dodana u bazu podataka', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for(add_location))
    return render_template('Products/addlocation.html', title="Add Location page", form=form, places=places, categories=categories)
```

**models.py**

```py
class AddLocation(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    desc = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    rating = db.Column(db.Float(2), nullable=False)
    cord = db.Column(db.Float(80), nullable=False, default=0)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
   #relationship 
    place_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('place.id'), nullable=False)
    place = db.relationship('Place', backref=db.backref('place', lazy=True))

    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    category = db.relationship('Category', backref=db.backref('category', lazy=True))
    
    image_1 = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False, default='Image.jpg')
    image_2 = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True, default='Image.jpg')
    image_3 = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True, default='Image.jpg')
    image_4 = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=True, default='Image.jpg')
```

**forms.py**

```py
class Location(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [validators.DataRequired()])
    desc = TextAreaField('Desc', [validators.DataRequired()])
    rating = FloatField('Rating', default=0)
    cord = FloatField('Cord', [validators.DataRequired()])
    
    image_1 = FileField('image 1', validators=[FileRequired(), FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'])])
    image_2 = FileField('image 2', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'])])
    image_3 = FileField('image 3', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'])])
    image_4 = FileField('image 4', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'jpeg'])])
```

**addlocation.html**

```
{% extends "layout.html"%}

{% block content %}
{% include 'admin/_mes.html'%}

<div class="containter">
    <!--Ep7-->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2 class="text-center"> Dodaj Lokaciju</h2>
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ render_field(form.name, class="form-control", placeholder="Dodaj naziv lokacije")}}
            {{ render_field(form.desc, class="form-control", placeholder="Dodaj deskripciju", rows="3")}}

            <!--Ep8-->
            <label for="place"> Izaberi grad</lable>
                <select name="place" id="place" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="">Izaberi grad</option>
                    {% for place in places %}
                    <option value="{{place.id}}"> {{place.name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <label for="category"> Izaberi Kategorije</lable>
                    {% for category in categories %}
                    <input type="checkbox" value="{{category.id}}">{{category.name}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
            </select>

            {{ render_field(form.rating, class="form-control", placeholder="Dodaj Rejting")}}
            {{ render_field(form.cord, class="form-control", placeholder="Dodaj Kordinate")}}
            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">{{render_field(form.image_1, class="form-control")}}</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">{{render_field(form.image_2, class="form-control")}}</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">{{render_field(form.image_3, class="form-control")}}</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">{{render_field(form.image_4, class="form-control")}}</div>
                </div>
            </div>

        <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info mt-4"> Dodaj </button>

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

I already once used similar code for User Registration and had no problems

Is it because i used **request.form.get?**

I tried **self** but I don't know how to properly implement it.
Adding **request.form.get** in **form = AddLocation(request.form)** also doesn't work.

Comment: Can't say for sure without definition of `AddLocation`, but maybe `request.form` needs to be some keyword parameter?

Comment: Its defiend in file models.py. Can u elaborate on request.form being keyword parameter?

Comment: Actually, the `AddLocation` is not a form, but a db model. You should probably use `Location` from `forms.py` like this: `form = Location(request.form)`

Comment: ye u right, it works :D

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering seems to be related to how you are initializing the AddLocation form. The AddLocation form appears to be defined in your forms.py as Location. Therefore, when you're trying to initialize the form in your add_location route, you should use Location(request.form) instead of AddLocation(request.form).

Here's how you should modify your add_location route in your Route.py file:

```
from forms import Location  # Make sure to import the Location form

@app.route('/addlocation', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_location():
    
    form = Location(request.form)  # Use Location instead of AddLocation
    places = Place.query.all()
    categories = Category.query.all()

# Rest of your code...
```

Make sure to update the import statement at the top of your Route.py file to correctly import the Location form from your forms.py module.

Additionally, it seems like you have a couple of issues in your HTML template:

The opening  tag for place and category should be spelled correctly:

```
<label for="place">Izaberi grad</label>


<label for="category">Izaberi Kategorije</label>
```

For the category checkboxes, you're using an  element instead of a  element. Update your code to properly use checkboxes:

```
<label for="category">Izaberi Kategorije</label>
{% for category in categories %}
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" value="{{ category.id }}">{{ category.name }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

You have a closing  tag for both place and category labels, which should be .

In your  element for the place, you should have a closing  tag instead of a closing  tag.

After making these changes, your HTML template should render correctly and work with the modified Python code. Make sure to check for any other possible issues in your code as well.